# List index out of range usando json.loads en Django

Tags: python, django, digitalocean

tengo un problema. El programa lo que hace es subir imágenes y desplegarlas en un index.html, en local funciona bastanta bien. Sube la imagen y la presenta en el index. No sé porque al pasar mi programa a Digital Ocean me aparece este error:

```
IndexError at /carros/
list index out of range
/workspace/carros/models.py, line 33, in new_name
```

El error me lo registra justo donde @property new_name
Yo no sé nada de Json, de hecho estoy tocando el código de un colega para subirloa Digital Ocean pero me parece curioso que sólo en local funcione. Tienen alguna idea de lo que está pasando?

> models.py

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from Clientes.models import Clientes
import json

class Carro(models.Model):
   placas=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   tipo=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   marca=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   modelo=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   año=models.IntegerField()
   vin=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   color=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   motor=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   agente_seguros=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   compañia_seguros=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   no_politica=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
   cliente= models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True)
   fotosCarro=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
   garantia=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
   fecha_registros = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True,blank=True)

#customize model property for main view of fotosCarro
   @property
   def new_name(self):
       temp=json.loads(self.fotosCarro)
       tempkey=sorted(temp.keys())
       for item in reversed(tempkey):
           if temp[item][1]=="on":
               return item;
       return list(json.loads(self.fotosCarro).keys())[0]
   def orig_name(self):
       return list(json.loads(self.fotosCarro).values())[0]

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.placas} {self.año}{self.marca} {self.modelo} {self.tipo}{self.motor}{self.vin}{self.color}' \
              f'{self.agente_seguros}{self.compañia_seguros}{self.no_politica}{self.cliente}{self.fotosCarro}{self.garantia}' \
              f'{self.fecha_registros}'
```

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre (ya que no se nada de django) es que el json contenga unicamente un object vacío (es decir, que el json contenga algo como {}). Espero haber ayudado a poder diagnosticar mejor el problema.

Comment: ah ok entonces te refieres a que está vacío?

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre un archivo vacío y un object vacío. En el segundo caso, hay algo en el archivo, pero ese algo (sea un object o un array) está vacío.

Comment: muchas gracias!! me ayudaste a comprender

Comment: De nada Anaid c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar esa clase de errores, tienes que verificar que tu lista no este vacía, el error lo lanza alguna de las dos propiedades, la de new_name o la de orig_name, necesitas validar antes que exista los keys() y los values() antes de convertirlo a lista e intentar obtener el primer elemento de la lista.

Aqui tienes una manera de como lo puedes implementar:

```
@property
def new_name(self):
   temp=json.loads(self.fotosCarro)
   tempkey=sorted(temp.keys())
   for item in reversed(tempkey):
       if temp[item][1]=="on":
           return item;
   if json.loads(self.fotosCarro).keys():
        return list(json.loads(self.fotosCarro).keys())[0]
    return None

def orig_name(self):
    if json.loads(self.fotosCarro).values():
        return list(json.loads(self.fotosCarro).values())[0]
    return None
```